# Fix request failed using php

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I make an api using Linkedin for website. After created all files, my application run fine but the only that has problem is when I try to allow the website, gives me this errors:
[image]
my purpose is to access in this page:
[image]

My code has error in this line:

[image]

init.php

```
<?php 
SESSION_start();
$client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$client_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$redirect_uri="http://localhost/gmail-connect.php/callback.php";
$csrf_token = "random_int(1111111, 9999999)";
$scopes="r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress";


function curl($url, $parameters)
{

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$header =[];
$header[] = "Content-type:applicationx-www-form-urlencoded";

$result = curl_exec($ch);
return $result;
}

function getCallback()
{
    $client_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$client_secret="jxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$redirect_uri="http://localhost/gmail-connect.php/callback.php";
$csrf_token ="random_int(1111111, 9999999)";
$scopes="r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress";

}

if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {

    $code = $_REQUEST['code'];
    $url = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
    $params = [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    'code' => $code,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
];

$accessToken = curl($url, http_build_query($params));
$accessToken = json_decode($accessToken)->access_Token;

$URL="https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,pictureUrls::(original),headline,publicProfileUrl,location,industry,positions,email-address)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=" .$accessToken;
$user = file_get_contents($url, false);
return(json_decode($user));


}

?>
```

Callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once "init.php";
$user = getCallback();
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
header("location: landing.php");
?>
```

And this is the landing page:

```
<?php
require "init.php";
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {


$user = 0;
}
?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>profile</title>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:200px; text-align:center;">
<div>
<h1>successful</h1>
<h1>here is describing your details info</h1>
<label style="font-weight:600">First Name</label><br>
<label><?php echo $user['firstName'] ?></label><br><br>

<label style="font-weight:600">Last Name</label><br>
<label><?php echo $user['lastName'] ?></label><br><br>


<label style="font-weight:600">Email address</label><br>
<label><?php echo $user['emailaddress'] ?></label><br><br>


<label style="font-weight:600">Headline</label><br>
<label><?php echo $user['headline'] ?></label><br><br>

<label style="font-weight:600">Industry</label><br>
<label><?php echo $user['industry'] ?></label><br><br>
<button><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the x it is for secure reason, I have put `$client_secret=""`, `$client_id=""`.
In this project I want to see my profile completed with details  on landing page and not empty as it's show here for example in first name to be writen a name and ect.

how to fix those errors,thanks

Comment: Why you cannot paste code here?

Comment: the problem with posting images and not text is that if i want to test your code I have to type it out, and I'm not going to do that.

Comment: @IdontDownVote if don't want then I suppose it is not important to write a comment.

Comment: @ventaquil , I add code latetly. I try to access on the another  page(landing)  to see my information but bring me to the first page which is the sign page. Can you provide a solution, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code before $accessToken :

```
$context = stream_context_create(
                    array('http' => 
                        array('method' => 'POST',
                        )
                    )
                );



    return true;
```

this make solute the error message

Answer (score 1):

The first error (Undefined property) is because the HTTP request didn't get a valid response ($accessToken) in:

$accessToken = curl();

This could be because the URL requested is invalid. You can:

- Check if `$params` array is correctly set. Call `print_r($params)` or `print_r(http_build_query($params))` before calling curl to check it.
- Check if the `curl()` call has the right parameters (url and parameters) it could be better to use only a full url ($url . "?" .  http_build_query($params)) if the request is using GET, but
- The accessToken API must be requested as POST request (not GET), so make sure your cUrl call sends a POST request (See: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#)

The second error is related to the first one, because the access token is empty, you get a HTTP 400 error (bad request). So if you fix the first step the second could be fine.

Comment: by calling `print_r($params)`  now the error is refering to this code: `$accessToken = curl($url, http_build_query($params));` .

Comment: I put the code of init.php , a minutes ago, which it's has $accessToken with $params and I try it print_r($params) but give error(parse error:unexpected '$accessToken'(T_VARIABLE)). I put `print_r($params)` before accessToken in the file init.php, maybe I make mistake.